# Remove specific columns using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have set of files in ADLS. Number of columns varies in each file.

File 1 will have the columns : Row_Number, Col_A, Col_B, null

File 2 will have the columns : Row_Number, Col_1, Col_2, Col_3 , null

File 3 will have the columns : Row_Number, Col_A1, Col_A2, null

There will be more than 50 files in my ADLS.
I would need to remove first and last column in each file or to be specific , I need to remove columns which has columns names as Row_Number and null.

Can any help me what should be my expressions in Derived column / Select.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your last column header the string "null" or is it blank? i.e. is that a CSV file like this for the header? Row_Number, Col_A, Col_B,

Comment: If your header is not defined like in my example above, then you will use that text delimited dataset as a source in your data flow without a defined schema in the dataset. Instead, Import Projection in the data flow source and the last column will be defined with syntax like this '_c4'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a Select rule with this for the matching condition:

name != 'Row_Number' && name != 'null' && left(name,2) != '_c'

and this for the output column name: $$

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark. Can you tell me what does left(name,2) != '_c' filter out?

Comment: Have a look at my question above. If you have a header that is blank in an ADF dataset, data flows will give it a junk name like "_c4". This rule filters those out since you said you wanted to filter out columns called "null" and I wasn't sure how they actually appear in your source data.

Comment: that `left(name,2) != '_c'` is gold - late binding / schemaless scenarios in ADF are currently labeling skipped / blank / extra columns with `_cN` where N is 1... so this was very helpful in cleaning up.  I used it in conjunction with the source dataset's range being set to A1:AZ10000 or some other large 'grab' from the source Excel file when I had skipped columns in the sheet (with no header name, which otherwise generates an error)