# Remove or ignore last column in CSV file in Azure

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

I have a CSV file on a SFTP which has 13 columns, but annoyingly the last one has no data or header, so basically there is an extra comma at the end of every record:

```
PGR,Concession ,Branch ,Branch Name ,Date ,Receipt ,Ref/EAN,Till No ,Qty , Price  , Discount , Net Price  ,
```

I want to import this file into a SQL table in Azure using copy Activity in Data Factory, but I'm getting this error:
[image]

I know if I manually open the file and right click and remove column M (which is completely blank), then it works fine.  But this needs to be an automated process, can someone assist please?  Not too familiar with Data Flow in ADF so that could be an option, or I can use Logic App to access the file too if ADF is not the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is to Parse the csv file and directly send only the required data to Azure sql from logic app using `SQL Server` Connector. Here is the screenshot of my logic app.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

Alternatively you can remove last column from ADF by using a Select rule with the required condition.

```
name != 'null' && left(name,2) != '_c'
```

Because the header of the ADF dataset is blank, data flows will name it "_c(< Some Column No>)" we are using `left(name,2) != '_c'`.

**REFERENCES:**
[Remove specific columns using Azure Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63781415/remove-specific-columns-using-azure-data-factory)

Comment: Hi @SwethaKandikonda-MT, I like the LogicApp solution, but I've never used Parse CSV before and it looks like I need an API key, is it able to access SFTP?  Failing that is there an alternative where I can export the CSV (with only the columns I want so without the last 13th blank column) to a BLOB storage instead?  That way I will then have a clean file which I can import into SQL, as it turns out the table is actually on Prem and not in Azure, which is fine as I can handle that with data factory, so basically just need a way to clean the original file up.

Comment: You can create an API key from Plumsail itself. This is a third-party connector but works like a gem. https://auth.plumsail.com/account/login?ReturnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Faccount.plumsail.com%2F